# How can I use javascript to alert these PHP error messages?

Tags: javascript

How can I javascript alert my php error messages? Here is my code:

```
<?php echo showmessage($msg)?>
```

I want to make it into an alert, how can I do that?

Comment: side note: i'd recommend finding alternatives to an alert, e.g.: jquery UI model or equiv, "warning/notice/info"-styled paragraph on the page, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `json_encode` makes sure that characters that needs to be escaped are escaped.

```
<script>
  alert(<?php echo json_encode($msg); ?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("The error is  <?php echo $msg ?>");
    history.back();
  </script>
<?php
```

Or

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert(Message here)';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: hopefully the message has no " or line breaks in it.

Comment: a " wouldn't break it.

Comment: True, I'll leave it as " " then.

Comment: @Waclock really? `alert("The error is  I am going to break " because I am mean");`